# Parse XML partially

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

i have a problem parsing following (shortened) XML-file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- DOCTYPE nitf PUBLIC "-//IPTC-NAA//DTD NITF-XML 3.0//EN" "nitf.dtd" -->
<nitf> 
  <head> 
    <title>EU-Regierungschefs streiten über Waffen für Syrien</title> 
  </head>  
  <body> 
    <body.head> 
      <hedline> 
        <hl1>EU-Regierungschefs streiten über Waffen für Syrien</hl1> 
      </hedline>  
    </body.head>  
    <body.content>
      <p> [...] </p>

      <block style="EXTERNAL-LINKS"> 
        <p> 
          <a href="http://dpaq.de/CyyZL">EU und Syrien</a> 
        </p>  
        <p> 
          <a href="http://dpaq.de/WzLWU">EU und Russland</a> 
        </p> 
      </block>  
      <media media-type="image">
        <media-reference alternate-text="Merkel und Barroso" height="600" mime-type="image/jpeg" name="large_4_3" source="../dpa-bzv_myline-images/large/jpeg-1484DE008774AFFD-20130315-img_41077628.original.large-4-3-800-252-0-2976-2041.jpg" width="800"/>  
        <media-caption> 
          <p> [...] </p> 
        </media-caption> 
      </media> 
    </body.content>  
    <body.end/> 
  </body> 
</nitf>
```

The PHP-part looks like this:

```
if (file_exists($path)) {
    $xml = simplexml_load_file($path);
    var_dump($xml->body->{'body.content'});
}
```

As expected, the XML-content is parsed correctly. This is, where my problem begins. `<body.content>` contains HTML-tags, which are parsed, too, but i would like the content to be treated as a string, to output it directly to display the HTML as it is.

What would be the best way to solve this?

Comment: The *correct* way would be to wrap that data in CDATA tags.. but I'm guessing you don't have access to the source?

Comment: @MikeB Correctly! These files are uploaded by FTP push.

Comment: What do you think about that as a crutch: replace '<body.content>' by '<body.content><![CDATA[' and '</body.content>' by ']]></body.content>' ?? would be much simpler than anything i can imagine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without modifying the source (e.g. to wrap the relevant section in a CDATA block, or entity-escape it), you cannot tell an XML parser to simply not parse part of the document.

However, you can ask SimpleXML to turn a particular section of the document back into XML using its [`->asXML()` method](http://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.asxml.php), e.g.

```
echo $xml->body->{'body.content'}->block[0]->asXML();
```

<kbd>[Live Demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/5MFHyx)</kbd>

Note that this requires that the embedded HTML is valid XML (e.g. no unclosed tags or unescaped `&`s), otherwise the parser will simply error trying to process it.

I also notice that `body.content` itself doesn't contain HTML, it contains various different content, which is why I've descended one step further in my example.

Comment: Well, thank you so much! What i considered to do is to awkward to tell...